# 90s Movie/TV series in which a boy travels to different worlds, fighting an evil scientist

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Saw this movie/TV series the 90s, though could have been made in the 80s. It was a live action show.

- Boy meets a scientist, who can open a portal to different worlds
- They are being chased by an evil scientist, who wants to destroy the world. He follows them from world to world, attacking them.
- Each movie (or TV series? I can't remember) has them going to a different world. In one, war has destroyed the world, and now only human like dolls exist in a carnival type world. In another, they go to a world they are are tiny, and a little baby chases them.
- Boy meets with a girl from the future, who has been fighting all her life, and is surprised to hear our hero's world is peaceful. In other episode, they come to our normal world, and the girl has to pretend to a normal teenager.
- In the end, we find that the

  > Scientist helping the hero was the bad guy, and the evil scientist they had been fighting was actually trying to save the world.

Hero saves the world, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)*

[image: Cover of the first installment, "Planet of the Dino-Knights"]

> The series concerns a device, found by humans in the 25th century, called the Nullifier. This device is said to be capable of destroying the universe. Realizing the danger, a man called Irwin 1138 splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are then dispersed through time. However, a scientist called Dr. Zoetrope finds out where the pieces are located and, with the help of his time traveling armor, sets about reassembling the device. Along with 20th century teenager Josh Kirby, and a half-human warrior known as Azabeth Siege, Irwin 1138 sets about thwarting Dr. Zoetrope's plans.
>
> Josh Kirby is 14 years of age in 9th grade and his journey starts when he is accidentally pulled into the fight between Irwin and Zoetrope when a piece of the Nullifier lands in his time. He has to overcome his homesickness for small-town America, helped by befriending the alien warrior-girl Azabeth, and saving her life, a result of this being that she is bound by oath to protect him. After a series of adventures including seeing the year 70,379 where humans have become tyrannical giants, a world populated by living toys, and Azabeth’s home world where humans are the hated enemy of her people, The Kang, he eventually is confronted by a shocking betrayal by Irwin before he discovers that he must choose between Azabeth's survival and fulfilling his Time Warrior destiny.